# In-text reference (APA style) for website

Tags: citations

How do I make an in-text citation for an information acquired from a website (If the writer and publication date is known)? Is it necessary to write out the full URL? I found [APAstyle.org's explanation](http://apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-references.aspx#Websites) ambiguous.

Comment: We would probably be able to help you more easily if you could edit your question to explain in more detail what exactly about the explanation at APAstyle.org is ambiguous. (Incidentally, the link throws my browser into an endless loop, but I assume you don't mean *that* by "ambiguous".)

Answer (score 1):

From [Penn State University Libraries](https://www.libraries.psu.edu/psul/researchguides/citationstyles/APA_intext_citation.html#in-text-citation)

> APA in-text citation style uses the author's last name and the year of
>   publication, for example: (Field, 2005). For direct quotations,
>   include the page number as well, for example: (Field, 2005, p. 14).
>   For sources such as websites and e-books that have no page numbers,
>   use a paragraph number.

So in your case you could cite (Author name, Year, Paragraph Number).

Here is some more information when you do not have page numbers from [Prudue University OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/03/)

> **Sources Without Page Numbers**
>
> When an electronic source lacks page numbers, you should try to
>   include information that will help readers find the passage being
>   cited. When an electronic document has numbered paragraphs, use the
>   abbreviation "para." followed by the paragraph number (Hall, 2001,
>   para. 5). If the paragraphs are not numbered and the document includes
>   headings, provide the appropriate heading and specify the paragraph
>   under that heading. Note that in some electronic sources, like Web
>   pages, people can use the Find function in their browser to locate any
>   passages you cite.

Comment: How one can distinguish a web source from a printed document then?

Comment: @Pınar In your Bibliography/reference list you would list a website in the following format:  Author, A.A.. (Year, Month Date of Publication). Article title. Retrieved from URL. See [this page from Prudue](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/10/) for more info.